# Maven TinyB failure: package tinyb does not exist

Tags: java, maven, jar, bluetooth

I am trying to do a program where I need using Aws sdk and TinyB library. FOr that reason I have decided to use maven to create the project and resolve the dependencies. However, I have been trying to compile the project with the package TinyB for more than a week without success. I would be very grateful if someone could teach me what I am doing wrong.

The failure message I am receving is the following:

> C:/Users/fran/Desktop/RSSI_AWS_PROJECT/BleDistanceMeasurement/src/main/java/org/tfm/app/BleMng.java:[7,1]
>   package tinyb does not exist

And my pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.tfm.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>BleDistanceMeasurement</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>BleDistanceMeasurement</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.327</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-iot</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.34</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-iot-device-sdk-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-iot-device-sdk-java-samples</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.kura</groupId>
      <artifactId>tinyb</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>tinyb</id>
      <url>https://repo.eclipse.org/content/groups/releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I have opened the project with Eclipse IDE to know what is happening but I have seen that eclipse is recognizing the dependencies correctly.

[TinyB dependencie scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffwks.jpg)

[Project dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFp7A.jpg)

TinyB library I have downloaded and compiled the source from here:

https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb

But there is no maven repositories directly from intel so I have added the one form eclipse kura:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sputnikdev/bluetooth-manager-tinyb -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sputnikdev</groupId>
    <artifactId>bluetooth-manager-tinyb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This one gives me problems when compiling, it seems as if the repository hasn't been downloaded. But the foder with the jar exists (it shows the error quoted previously).

I have made some little programs with TinyB and they are working perfectly, so the program is compiled and installed correctly. The problem is I am not using maven in this little programs (I just add the import and point to the .jar when executing). Like this:

```
sudo java -cp examples/java/HelloTinyB.jar:/usr/lib/lib/java/tinyb.jar HelloTinyB
```

I have also try this other maven repository:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sputnikdev/bluetooth-manager-tinyb -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sputnikdev</groupId>
    <artifactId>bluetooth-manager-tinyb</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In this case it recognizes the dependencies and compiles. The problem is it gives error when I try to execute the program:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Native library is out of date. Please update the native library.
>       at tinyb.BluetoothManager.getBluetoothManager (BluetoothManager.java:317)

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: [Maven - Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

Comment: yes, I also installed the jar separatedly without success. It is installed correctly and appear in .m2 folder but when compiling it is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to use eclipse Kura too.
Did you achieve making it work?

I have the same issue.

By the way, I see that maybe your dependencies are not really valid, as sputnikdev has a library over tinyB, but, finally I have the same problem than you. These are my main dependencies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sputnikdev/org.eclipse.smarthome.binding.bluetooth.transport.tinyb -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sputnikdev</groupId>
    <artifactId>bluetooth-manager</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>intel-iot-devkit</groupId>
    <artifactId>tinyb</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sputnikdev</groupId>
    <artifactId>bluetooth-manager-tinyb</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I found that TinyB be is already used in Kura as main library to manage Bluetooth. Hope you find it useful. http://eclipse.github.io/kura/dev/bluetooth-le-apis.html

Comment: But...is it dependant on OSGI infrastructure?  Can you launch it without OSGI? Do you have an example? Thank you very much!

Comment: OSGi & Kura are different things. OSGi is a Java framework which allows to develop apps in a dynamical way using bundles instead of having a monolitic architecture. Kura is a framework for IoT gateways. One of its main features is that it is based on OSGi. Kura offers different features already built-in, as it can be it GUI, could connection, etc. One of this features is BLE communication, which in this case it has been done using TinyB library, but this is already built-in. You only need to learn hown to use its APIs. If you install kura will see TinyB bundle is already installed and running.